# Is it possible to use the Node testing library Rewire to mock two calls to the same function so they return different results?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, mocking

I'm new to mocking in Node. I'm using the library Rewire which seems to be one of the better options. I've run into a issue where I need to mock the same function twice within a method so that they return different results:

```
const tourId: string = await redis.read(accessToken, false);
if (tourId === null) {
  logger.warn('invalid token', { accessToken });
  throw boom.notFound(codes.RECORD_NOT_FOUND);
}

logger.warn('found an access token', { tourId });

const tourResponse: string = await redis.read(tourId, false);
if (tourResponse === null) {
  logger.warn('tour not found', { accessToken, tourId });
  throw boom.notFound(codes.RECORD_NOT_FOUND);
}
```

In the above example, I call the function `redis.read()` twice. In order to properly get the test coverage I want I would need to mock those two calls differently which I'm struggling with. Here is a test case I have so far:

```
it('returns a 404 error if access token not found in redis', async () => {
  service.__set__({
    redis: {
      read: (accessToken: string): string | null => null,
    },
  });

  service.getHandler('12345').catch((result: boom) => {
    expect(result.isBoom, 'should be boom error').to.be.true;
    expect(result.output.payload.statusCode, 'should be 404 error').to.equal(404);
    expect(result.output.payload.message, 'should be RECORD_NOT_FOUND error').to.equal(codes.RECORD_NOT_FOUND);
    });
});
```

Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: It isn't shown how you use Rewire. Is it really needed? Couldn't redis.read method be mocked?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here: `sinon.stub()` has an `onCall()` method you can use to change the output for the :nth call.

https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/#stuboncalln-added-in-v18

```
it('returns an iTour instance if found in redis', async () => {
      const callback = sinon.stub();

      callback.onCall(0).returns('12345');
      callback.onCall(1).returns('67890');

      service.__set__({
        redis: {
          read: () => callback(),
        }
      });

      service.getHandler('12345').catch((result: boom) => {
        expect(result.isBoom, 'should be boom error').to.be.true;
        expect(result.output.payload.statusCode, 'should be 404 error').to.equal(404);
        expect(result.output.payload.message, 'should be RECORD_NOT_FOUND error').to.equal(codes.RECORD_NOT_FOUND);
      });
    });
```